# Set the selected language for Text to Speech in Java

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, locale, text-to-speech

I have a list of many languages that the user can select for a text-to-speech operation. My wish is to set the language that the user has selected for tts to function. But setLanguage requires a Locale, and by that stage, I only have a String. So this is what I have tried to do, but I get a nullpointer exception:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Languages currentLanguages = languagesList.get(getAdapterPosition());
    Snackbar snackbar;
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, currentLanguages.getLocaleDisplay() + " selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Next", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    String chosenLanguage = localeDisplay.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(chosenLanguage);
                    intent.putExtra("language_key", chosenLanguage);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    Locale chosenLocale = localeDisplay.getTextLocale();
    chosenLocale.getLanguage();
    myTTS.setLanguage(chosenLocale);
    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(grey_blue);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

I would be extremely grateful for some pointers as to why this is not working. Thanks!

Here is the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.madhatter.nat.pronounce, PID: 864
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setLanguage(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at com.madhatter.nat.pronounce.LanguagesRecycler.RecyclerAdapter$MyViewHolder$1.onClick(RecyclerAdapter.java:63)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Edit: getAdapterPosition() gives me the number of the language that is clicked. How can I get to set the language of the Text-To-Speech engine based on its position in my recycler list?

Comment: NullPointerException where? Show to logcat, please

Comment: @cricket_007 Hi, added logcat

Comment: And what is `localeDisplay.getTextLocale()` returning?

Comment: which line is `RecyclerAdapter.java:63`?

Comment: It's returning en_US even though I clicked on Arabic. I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: @MattClark it's chosenLocale.getLanguage();